# Print out an object with a for/in loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print out a list of people and all of the people and information are in the object, I am trying to figure out how to use a for/in loop to print out the object.

Thank you!
Here's my code.
http://pastebin.com/TyUXF7Tf

Comment: Print out for the user or for the developer?

Comment: `for(var bill in object)` You're getting "object is not defined"?

Comment: Yeah I'm also getting list is not defined

Comment: You've defined `friends` not `object`

Comment: I'm using codeacademy and this is what i'm getting http://i.imgur.com/sbxkba0.png

Comment: This is your problem `for(var bill in object) ` there is no `object`

Comment: Ok I changed it, this is what I'm getting now http://i.imgur.com/J1O42kP.png @Popnoodles

Comment: Google javascript foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
var friends = {
  "bill" : {
    "firstName" : "Bill" ,
    "lastName" : "Bob" ,
    "number" : "(111) 111-1111" ,
    "address" : ['1111 1 Road','1 City','1 Province','11111']
  } , {
  "steve" : {
    "firstName" : "Steve" ,
    "lastName" : "G. Jones" ,
    "number" : "(123) 456-7891" ,
    "address" : ['1234 Steve Road','Seattle','WA','12345']
  }
}

var listLoop = function(friends) {
  for(var person in friends) {
    console.log("Whole Person: " , person);
    console.log("First Name: " , person.firstName);
    console.log("Last Name: " , person.lastName);
    console.log("Number: " , person.number);
    console.log("Address: ", person.address);
  }
};
```